# Creating a Cordova project with MobileFirst CLI, fails to run Android command

Tags: android, cordova, command-line-interface, ibm-mobilefirst

When I run the `mfp` Cordova create command, I get an error message that says it failed to run the Android command. I have installed the latest Android SDK, set the `ANDROID_HOME` to the Android Studio location, and added the path to the `android.bat` file to the PATH variable, but still getting this error. In the project directory that is created, some of the default artefacts are created, but some are missing. The `application-descriptor.xml` file and `mobilefirst` directory are missing.

Comment: And your CLI version and build number is......?

Comment: You are also not mentioning the *actual* error you get.

Comment: ANDROID_HOME should be set to the android sdk installation folder and not Android Studio location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my ~/.bash_profile I have the following set:

`#export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/idanadar/Documents/MobileFirst/Setup/Android/"`
`#export ANDROID_ROOT="/Users/idanadar/Documents/MobileFirst/Setup/Android/platform-tools/"`

Then in Terminal I did: `mfp cordova create`, followed the interactive instructions, added the Android environment and was able to successfully create it.

In the project folder I have application-descriptor.xml at the root folder, and a mobilefirst folder with wlapp files for -android, -ios and -all.

Comment: I did have the Path set wrong, fixed it as you said, re-ran the command and...error says "Please install Android target "android-22." I had latest version 23 installed, so I installed 22, re-ran the command and it worked, finally. It is CLI v7.1 part number CN79NEN. How do I tell the build number?

Comment: By running "mfp -v". More with "mfp help".